# Opening InMemory Table to execute some SQL gives Runtime Error 445 - Object doesn't support this action?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vba

I have a InMemory that gets created, what I then want to do is run INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries on the table. The code i have at the moment is below, I create a new InMemory table, add it to the map (which works).

```
    Dim pInMemTable As ITable
    'create Temp DP table
    Set pWSF = New InMemoryWorkspaceFactory
    Dim PName As esriSystem.IName
    Set PName = pWSF.Create("fred", "InMemory", Nothing, 0)
    ' Debug.Print ">>" + PName.NameString + "<<"
    Set pFWS = PName.Open

    Dim pFlds As IFieldsEdit
    Set pFlds = New esriGeoDatabase.Fields
    pFlds.AddField MakeField("OBJECTID", esriFieldTypeOID)
    pFlds.AddField MakeField("DP_REF", esriFieldTypeString, 10)
    pFlds.AddField MakeField("WANTED", esriFieldTypeString, 1)

    Dim pUID As New UID
    pUID.Value = "esriGeodatabase.Object"

    Dim ptable As ITable
    Set ptable = pFWS.CreateTable("DP_Temp", pFlds, pUID, Nothing, "")
   ' Debug.Print ptable.

    Dim pSAT As IStandaloneTable
    Set pSAT = New StandaloneTable
    Set pSAT.Table = ptable
    pSAT.Name = "DP_Temp999"

    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

    Dim pSATC As IStandaloneTableCollection
    Set pSATC = pMxDoc.FocusMap

    pSATC.AddStandaloneTable pSAT
    pMxDoc.UpdateContents

    Set pInMemTable = pSAT

    Dim path As String
    path = "InMemory/DP_Temp999"
    If pWSF Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "pwsf is nothing"
    Else
       ' MsgBox "pwsf is something"
        'MsgBox pWSF.WorkspaceDescription(False)

        'pwsf.Open(
        Set pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(path, 0) ' **********PWS doesnt get set***********
        If pWS Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "PWS IS NOTHING" 
        Else
            MsgBox ("Yes!!")
        End If

    End If
```

but the code fails where PWS is getting set as it always returns as Nothing. I have tried various ways of setting the path value e.g. "InMemory/DP_Temp999", "In_Memory/DP_Temp" and trying the "\" as opposed to "/" but it still comes back as nothing.
Does anyone have any ideas please? or is there a better way of executing SQL on a table that will allow SELECT, DELETE and INSERTS.

******UPDATE****
Right I have been working on this for a few days have have been able to set pWS, by casting by ptable to a idataset object and then setting pWS to the pdataset propertyset properties which works. However I have then tried the following code, to see if SQL can be executed

```
    If pWS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "PWS IS NOTHING"
    Else
        'MsgBox ("Yes!!")
        Dim pWorkspaceProperties As IWorkspaceProperties
        Set pWorkspaceProperties = pWS

        Dim pWSProperty As IWorkspaceProperty
        Set pWSProperty = pWorkspaceProperties.Property(esriWorkspacePropertyGroup, esriWorkspacePropCanExecuteSQL)
        If pWSProperty.IsSupported = True Then
            MsgBox "SQL is supported"
            Dim sql As String
            'sql = "select * from 'DP_TEMP';"
            sql = "UPDATE dp_temp set dp_temp.[DP_REF] = 'Test';"
            pWS.ExecuteSQL sql
        Else
            MsgBox "SQL is not supported"
        End If
    End If
```

When the code is run, the pWSProperty.IsSupported returns as True, however when the .ExecuteSQL method is run, I get the following error Runtime Error 445 - Object doesn't support this action. So I am a bit confused as to whether SQL can be run or not.

Comment: What are the other variables (pFWS and pWS)?

Comment: pFWS is IFeatureWorkSpace, and pWS is IWorkspace. They were global variables, but makes no difference if I put it within the procedure.

Comment: Can you try this using a ScratchWorkspace instead of an InMemoryWorkspace? The InMemory workspaces do have some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

This code gets the IWorkspace (I added the declarations for the pFWS and pWS into the code to make it work in my example)

```
        Dim pInMemTable As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable
        'create Temp DP table
        Dim pWSF As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.InMemoryWorkspaceFactory
        Dim PName As ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IName
        PName = pWSF.Create("fred", "InMemory", Nothing, 0)
        ' Debug.Print ">>" + PName.NameString + "<<"
        Dim pFWS As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace = PName.Open
        Dim pWS As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace

        ' the rest of your code 

        If pWSF Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("pwsf is nothing")
        Else
            ' MsgBox "pwsf is something"
            'MsgBox pWSF.WorkspaceDescription(False)

            'pwsf.Open(
            'pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(path, 0) ' **********PWS doesnt get set***********
            pWS = pFWS
            If pWS Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox("PWS IS NOTHING")
            Else
                MsgBox("Yes!!")
            End If

        End If
```

Comment: Ken, Looking at your code you have set pWS to the Featureworkspace (pFWS) , which i have got to work, however doesn't it need to be set to the pWSF (workspace factory), so that I can open the inmemory table and then run the executesql method?

Comment: Canty seem to edit my comment above...Here is a link which shows what i want to do (example is a FGDB table) http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=230422

Comment: You're correct on that. Is the workspace you're really after the DP_Temp table instead of the DP_Temp999 table?

Comment: The table name is called DP_Temp,The alias name of the table when it is added to the TOC is DP_Temp999, I just left it as I was trying to figure if changing the name made any difference. So yes the workspace I am after is the DP_Temp table.

Comment: Original question updated